# How to count clicked buttons by adding each counted click button(only one on div) together

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to count in JS two buttons if they clicked and then lower them to one couse I need confirmation of action only once in div. For example if Button1 and Button2 is clicked then I need to have the number 1. If Button1 and Button2 and Button11 and Button22 is clicked together I need to have the number 2.

Now I just need to add two counting to each other but I don't now how to finish it.
Anyone have any solution.

I have this code(http://jsfiddle.net/rjopn78x/253/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hej').removeClass('selected3').addClass('black');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('itemitem').removeClass('green').addClass('item');
});

$( "button#jQueryColorChange" ).click(function() {
  $(this).addClass( "selected" );
  $(this).text("TRENING");
  $(this).addClass( "selected" );
});
$( "button#jQueryColorChange2" ).click(function() {
  $(this).addClass( "selected2" );
  $(this).text("ZNAM");
  $(this).addClass( "selected2" );
});

$(".Button1").click(function(){
           $('#itemitem').removeClass( "green" );
$('#itemitem').addClass( "orange" );
   $('item').removeClass( "green" );
   $('Button').removeClass( "selected3" );
   $(this).addClass( "Button" );
   $('#hej').addClass( "selected4" );
   $('Button').removeClass( "selected" );
});
$(".Button2").click(function(){
        $('#itemitem').removeClass( "orange" );
    $('#itemitem').addClass( "green" );
  $('item').removeClass( "orange" );
  $('Button').removeClass( "selected4" );
   $(this).addClass( "Button" );
   $('#hej').addClass( "selected3" );
   $('Button').removeClass( "selected2" );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hejnowe').removeClass('selected5').addClass('black');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('itemitem2').removeClass('green').addClass('item2');
});

$( "button#jQueryColorChange11" ).click(function() {
  $(this).addClass( "selected" );
  $(this).text("TRENING");
  $(this).addClass( "selected" );
});
$( "button#jQueryColorChange22" ).click(function() {
  $(this).addClass( "selected2" );
  $(this).text("ZNAM");
  $(this).addClass( "selected2" );
});

$(".Button11").click(function(){
           $('#itemitem2').removeClass( "green" );
$('#itemitem2').addClass( "orange" );
   $('item2').removeClass( "green" );
   $('Button').removeClass( "selected5" );
   $(this).addClass( "Button" );
   $('#hejnowe').addClass( "selected6" );
   $('Button').removeClass( "selected" );
});
$(".Button22").click(function(){
        $('#itemitem2').removeClass( "orange" );
    $('#itemitem2').addClass( "green" );
  $('item2').removeClass( "orange" );
  $('Button').removeClass( "selected6" );
   $(this).addClass( "Button" );
   $('#hejnowe').addClass( "selected5" );
   $('Button').removeClass( "selected2" );
});

var count = 0;
var counta = 0;
        var btn = document.getElementById("jQueryColorChange");
        var btna = document.getElementById("jQueryColorChange11");
        var disp = document.getElementById("display");
        var dispa = document.getElementById("display2");
        var dispaa =  count + counta;

  if(dispaa < 2){
  btn.onclick = function (){
            count++;
            if (count > 1) {
        return false;
    }
    disp.innerHTML = count;
    }
        btna.onclick = function (){
            counta++;
            if (counta > 1) {
        return false;
    }
    dispa.innerHTML = counta;
    }
     var dispaa =  count + counta;
    }
    $('#something').click( function() { alert(dispaa); });
```

```css
div.menu {
    /* To correctly align image, regardless of content height: */
    top: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* To horizontally center images and caption */
    /* The width of the container also implies margin around the images. */
    width: 300px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: blue;
      text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
}

div.menu2 {
    /* To correctly align image, regardless of content height: */
    top: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* To horizontally center images and caption */
    /* The width of the container also implies margin around the images. */
    width: 300px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: blue;
      text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
}

.Button {
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 160px;
    height: 25px;
    background:grey;
    color: yellow;
}

.Button1 {
  text-align: center;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 160px;
    height: 25px;
    background:orange;
    color: yellow;
}

.Button2 {
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 160px;
    height: 25px;
    background:green;
    color: yellow;
}

.nowe.selected3 {
    color: black;
    background:green;
    border: solid;
}

.nowe.selected4 {
    color: black;
    background:orange;
    border: solid;
}

.selected {
    color: black;
    background:orange;
    border: solid;
}
.selected2 {
    color: black;
    background:green;
    border: solid;
}

.item {
    /* To correctly align image, regardless of content height: */
    top: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* To horizontally center images and caption */
    /* The width of the container also implies margin around the images. */
    width: 294px;
}

.ite {
background-color: white;
}

.item.orange {
background-color: orange;
}

.item.green {
background-color: green;
}

div.item:hover {
  border: 3px red solid;}
}

img33 {
    width: 294px;
    height: 201px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.caption {
  text-align: center;
    /* Make the caption a block so it occupies its own line. */
    display: block;
    color: black;
}

.Button {
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 160px;
    height: 25px;
    background:grey;
    color: yellow;
}

.Button11 {
  text-align: center;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 160px;
    height: 25px;
    background:orange;
    color: yellow;
}

.Button22 {
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 160px;
    height: 25px;
    background:green;
    color: yellow;
}
.nowe2.selected5 {
    color: black;
    background:green;
    border: solid;
}

.nowe2.selected6 {
    color: black;
    background:orange;
    border: solid;
}

.selected {
    color: black;
    background:orange;
    border: solid;
}
.selected2 {
    color: black;
    background:green;
    border: solid;
}

.item2 {
    /* To correctly align image, regardless of content height: */
    top: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* To horizontally center images and caption */
    /* The width of the container also implies margin around the images. */
    width: 294px;
}

.item2.orange {
background-color: orange;
}

.item2.green {
background-color: green;
}

div.item2:hover {
  border: 3px red solid;}
}

img33 {
    width: 294px;
    height: 201px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.caption {
  text-align: center;
    /* Make the caption a block so it occupies its own line. */
    display: block;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span id="display">0</span>
<span id="display2">0</span>
<a id="something">Text</a>
<div class="menu">
<button id="hej" class="nowe">GUY</button>
</div>
<div id="itemitem" class="item">
    <img id="33" src="http://smartangielski.j.pl/img/1bmix.jpg"/>
    <span class="caption"><u><b>Kacz</u></b>yński <u><b>łapie</u></b> motyle --- <b>catch[kacz] - łapać</b></span>
<button class="Button1" id="jQueryColorChange";>TRENING</button>
<br><br>
<button class="Button2" id="jQueryColorChange2";>ZNAM</button>
<br><br>
</div>
<div class="menu2">
<button id="hejnowe" class="nowe2">CATCH</button>
</div>
<div id="itemitem2" class="item2">
    <img id="33" src="http://smartangielski.j.pl/img/1bmix.jpg"/>
    <span class="caption"><u><b>Kacz</u></b>yński <u><b>łapie</u></b> motyle --- <b>catch[kacz] - łapać</b></span>
<button class="Button11" id="jQueryColorChange11" onclick="return myFunction()";;>TRENING</button>
<br><br>
<button class="Button22" id="jQueryColorChange22" onclick="return myFunction()";>ZNAM</button>
<br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to count?

Comment: I trying to count clicked buttons, but if in first div two buttons are clicked i want display only one click (this means that user was active in this div)

Comment: So youre counting the clicks of a div but not any concurrent clicks thereafter? BTW, I tried to follow the logic of your code got overwhelmed by it's enormity and underwhelmed by it's pupose. jQuery handles silly thing s like a billion buttons that do nothing without evfen using id.

Comment: Does clicking a button a second time cause it to be "unclicked", i.e. no longer counts as a click?

Comment: @kmoser - yes, it no no longer counts as a click in case of second click

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
var count = 0;
var counta = 0;
        var btn = document.getElementById("jQueryColorChange");
        var btna = document.getElementById("jQueryColorChange11");
        var disp = document.getElementById("display");
        var dispa = document.getElementById("display2");
        var di = document.getElementById("display3"); ///here
  
  btn.onclick = function (){
            count++;
            if (count > 1) {
        return false;
    }
    disp.innerHTML = count;
    di.innerHTML = Number(dispa.innerHTML) + Number(disp.innerHTML); ///here
    }
        btna.onclick = function (){
            counta++;
            if (counta > 1) {
        return false;
    }
    dispa.innerHTML = counta;
    di.innerHTML = Number(dispa.innerHTML) + Number(disp.innerHTML); //and here
    }
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4szxcvan/4/
Thanks for attention :)

Here is possibility to store score in localStorage: https://jsfiddle.net/nbL9zkpu/1/